# Moving large size directory using rsync

Tags: backup, rsync, storage-area-network

I plan to move from linux o/s a directory which is mounted on SAN(offboard) to external storage for backup. The dir size is `14TB`.

I do have experience moving files in/out using rsync but never done this with large size directories/files like now.

The directories are laid down in terms on year/month/days/hours hierarchy and support raw-logs for analysis.

**Problem**

So with the above told, due to resource restrictions I'm not able to move complete 14TB to external/backup storage space. The backup space I have currently is max 8 TB. So is there a command or switch / parameter i can tell rsync to only copies files to the mentioned size i.e TB only.

**NOTE**
I don't care less about the file nature its just the beyond certain size i don't want to move any data.

Comment: I have improved the question. Review please!

Comment: You need to decide which 6 TB of files to exclude.. and exclude them.  The computer isn't going to magically know.

Comment: @HopelessN00b I don't care less about the file nature its just the beyond certain size i don't want to move any data.

Comment: Do you want to transfer only the the first 8TB of files ?

Comment: first 8TB yes under main directory /store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get rsync to stop when it has copied a certain amount of bytes by providing a limit. You can run it normally

```
rsync -a /src/ /dest
```

and when /dest is full it will just stop with an error

```
 rsync: write failed on "...": No space left on device (28)
```

You could do something with a script

```
find /src -printf "%p %s\n" >filelist_size
```

Then use something like awk to read the `filelist_size` and print the file name to `filelist` if the sum of the filesizes is below some threshold.

You can then use the `files-from=filelist` argument to rsync.

It may be easier to write this in python.